# How do I find matching key/pair value from object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm working on a headless Shopify store using Gatsby, and am having some trouble building a robust product option picker.

I have an `options` object that looks like this:

```js
{
  extras: "Pouch only",
}
```

The key and value will be different for every product, so I won't know the values.

I have a `variants` array that will have a key/value pair that matches this object. Here is the shape of the variants array:

```js
[
  {
    extras: "Pouch only",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    extras: "Add tassel",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    extras: "Add charm",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    extras: "Add tassel & charm",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    sizes: "S",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    sizes: "M",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    sizes: "L",
    ...otherValues,
  },
  {
    sizes: "XL",
    ...otherValues,
  },
];
```

If I knew the name of the variant ahead of time, I could do something like this:

```js
const newVariant = variants.find((v) => {
  return v.extras === options.extras;
});
```

How can I do the same thing without knowing the name of the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object.entries` you can retrieve key/value pairs of the object, and check if `.some`(or `.every` depending on your needs) match:

```
const newVariant = variants.find((v) => Object.entries(options).some(([key, value]) => v[key] === value));
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas! This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take the entries of the `option` object and stringify them. Then, when searching through the `variants`, find (or filter) by the ones which have an entry matching the entry previously stringified:

```
const optionsEntryVariants = Object.entries(options).map(JSON.stringify);
const matchingVariants = variants.filter(
  variant => Object.entries(variant).some(
    entry => optionsEntryVariants.includes(JSON.stringify(entry))
  )
);
```

```js
const options = {
  extras: "Pouch only",
};

const optionsEntryVariants = Object.entries(options).map(JSON.stringify);

const variants = [
  {
    extras: "Pouch only",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    extras: "Add tassel",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    extras: "Add charm",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    extras: "Add tassel & charm",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    sizes: "S",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    sizes: "M",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    sizes: "L",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
  {
    sizes: "XL",
    someOtherProp: 'someOtherVal',
  },
];

const matchingVariants = variants.filter(
  variant => Object.entries(variant).some(
    entry => optionsEntryVariants.includes(JSON.stringify(entry))
  )
);

console.log(matchingVariants);
```

If you need *every* key-value pair in the `options` object to match, rather than just at least one to match, then change the `.some` to `.every`.

You could make the function a bit more efficient by making a Set of the stringified entries instead of using an array:

```
const optionsEntryVariants = new Set(
  Object.entries(options).map(JSON.stringify)
);
const matchingVariants = variants.filter(
  variant => Object.entries(variant).some(
    entry => optionsEntryVariants.has(JSON.stringify(entry))
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the object key for check. I think this solves your issue.

```js
const options = {
    extras: "Pouch only",
};

const otherValues = {};

const variants = [
    {
        extras: "Pouch only",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        extras: "Add tassel",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        extras: "Add charm",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        extras: "Add tassel & charm",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        sizes: "S",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        sizes: "M",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        sizes: "L",
        ...otherValues,
    },
    {
        sizes: "XL",
        ...otherValues,
    },
];

let optionsKey = '';
for (const opKey in options) {
    optionsKey = opKey
}

const newVariant = variants.find((v) => {
    for (const vKey in v) {
        if (vKey === optionsKey) {
            return v[vKey] === options[optionsKey];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `filter` and then `some` inside of it. Here is how:

```js
var data = data = [ { extras: "Pouch only" }, { extras: "Add tassel",size : 'SomeFilter' }, { extras: "Add charm" }, { extras: "Add tassel & charm", }, { sizes: "S" }, { sizes: "M", }, { sizes: "L" }, { sizes: "XL" }];

filter = { extras: "Pouch only" }

var objectToFilter = Object.entries(filter);

result1 = data.filter(val=>objectToFilter.some(([k,v])=>val.hasOwnProperty(k) && val[k].includes(v)));

filter = { extras: "Pouch only", size : 'SomeFilter'};

var objectToFilter = Object.entries(filter);

result2 = data.filter(val=>objectToFilter.some(([k,v])=>val.hasOwnProperty(k) && val[k].includes(v)));

console.log(result2);
```

Also if you want search for all values in filter, `some` could be replaced with `every` method.